# Issue with SQL Server FileStream

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, win32exception

We are currently reviewing an issue we have on one of our live environments where OpenFileStream (private method inside SqlFileStream C# class)

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the path specified at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream.OpenSqlFileStream(String path, Byte[] transactionContext, FileAccess access, FileOptions options, Int64 allocationSize)at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream..ctor(String path, Byte[] transactionContext, FileAccess access, FileOptions options, Int64 allocationSize)at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream..ctor(String path, Byte[] transactionContext, FileAccess access)
```

We have this working on another environment with no issues. The code we are using to call is as follows:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertFileSql, conn, transaction))
                {
                    string path = null;
                    byte[] context = null;
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        path = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("PathName"));
                        fileID = reader.GetGuid(reader.GetOrdinal("FileId"));
                        context = (byte[])reader[reader.GetOrdinal("Context")];
                    }

                    richTextBox1.AppendText(
                        string.Format("Path: {0}, FileID:{1}, content: {2}", path, fileID, Convert.ToString(context)));

                    using (SqlFileStream strm = new SqlFileStream(path, context, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        // copy the user file to the Filestream
                        inputFileStream.CopyTo(strm);
                    }
```

We've looked at ports/firewalls and even got to the point of seeing it is NtCreateFile failing inside the .Net Source code (with a value of 3221225530) but I can't find documentation on what that value or the value returned form *IOStatusBlock* which is one of the return parameters.

\\v02-A60EC2F8-2B24-11DF-9CC3-AF2E56D89593\dbFileStore\dbo\tblFile\DataFile\AC50B769-B6F8-43AA-B266-E4E837D78BA0\VolumeHint-HarddiskDmVolumes\\SQLData

Is there anything anybody else could suggest to look at, me and my team have been looking at this for best part of two days.

Cheers,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out that it was Veritas Storage Foundation which wasn't working with SQL FileStream, seems there is a bit of issue with VSF when performing Windows API calls.

Answer (score 2):

Though so much time has passed, we with SQL Server 2012 had this problem with ReadWrite. No problem with Read, no problem with Write, but only with ReadWrite.

Looks like something happens during install/uninstall of SQL Server updates - a registry setting gets accidently removed by setup. Readding it with .reg file:

```
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\FsctlAllowlist]
 "FSCTL_SQL_FILESTREAM_FETCH_OLD_CONTENT"=dword:00092560
```

Comment: Thanks for this I've upvoted as I know how difficult this was to diagnose! :) New Hard Disk without VSF seemed to sort it for us. That said I don't know whether they still have any issues as I've left the company now.